# Unexpected PHP warning errors

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, warnings

This is my first post here so apologies if the setup is kind of scrambled.

I am in the middle of working on an article database with MySQL and PHP.

I have a page which will show all articles by authors.  I am trying to have a link at the top of the page redirect with a few PHP `if statements` so the user will have to log in if not already.  If the user is already logged in (I haven't a PHP script for adding users to database yet, working on it) the redirect will load a form to submit a new article.

Controller (index.php) :

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
        '/includes/magicquotes.inc.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 
        '/includes/access.inc.php';

if (isset($_GET['add']))
  if (!userIsLoggedIn())
{
      include '/Test/articles/login.html.php';
      exit();
}
  else
{
      include 'form.html.php';
      exit();
}
                        :::PHP code left out for sake of example:::
include 'articles.html.php';
?>
```

`access.inc.php` contains `SESSION()` and `$sql` enrty scripts for entering and retaining username/passwords

`userIsLoggedIn()` is a function in `access.inc.php` (self explanatory)

`login.html.php` is my login form

`form.html.php` is the actual form to submit new articles

`articles.html.php` is the page which displays all of the articles in my database

My problem is that when I implement the `if statement` for the link to redirect to my login form when the user has not already logged in, I get PHP warnings when clicked which I don't get because my paths are correct for `/Test/articles/login.html.php` and I'm unsure what to do about it.

Warnings :

```
Warning: include(/Test/articles/login.html.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\articles\index.php on line 10

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/Test/articles/login.html.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\articles\index.php on line 10
```

Help please?  I'm at a total loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is almost never a good choice when it comes to determining folder structure because its unreliable.

Use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead.

```
if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
define('APP_FOLDER', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);

    include_once APP_FOLDER . 'includes/magicquotes.inc.php';
    require_once APP_FOLDER . 'includes/access.inc.php';

if (isset($_GET['addjoke']))
  if (!userIsLoggedIn())
{
      include APP_FOLDER . 'Test/articles/login.html.php';
      exit();
}
  else
{
      include APP_FOLDER . 'form.html.php';
      exit();
}
```

BTW, your real mistake was that you included a slash before Test (`/Test/...`) indicating that you want to access a folder residing on a root level of the web server.

Comment: Well thanks but I'm still getting the same errors  in OP, I'm thinking it has something to do with (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that all the files you are including actually exist? Don't worry about the PEAR include path. That's the default setting which you can safely ignore (its some kind of a last resort when looking for files to include).

Comment: Got it, it was an issue with XAMPP PHP system variables..no clue why it was configd differently but I managed to get it to work, thanks for your help!

Comment: rumspringa00: It would be useful to know what the issue was with XAMPP PHP system variables and how you fixed it - I now have the same issue.